# How does one make a macOS Scope Button in Interface Builder?

Tags: macos, button, interface-builder, appkit

Reading Apple's [macOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) section
on [Scope Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/buttons/scope-buttons/),
I looked for how one would make a Scope Button
for macOS
in Interface Builder (Xcode 9.0 beta 4).
I can't see how, although I've poked around a lot,
nor can I find information on the web.
Is the feature there somewhere?

A scope button is quite different from other buttons.
When unselected it looks like a label, with black text.
When selected it becomes a grey button with white text.

Comment: IB in Xcode 8 has a Round Rect Button and a Recessed Button - For use in scope bars and related filter rows. Are they removed in Xcode 9?

Answer (score 0):

The Interface Builder "Recessed Button" behaves like a scope button.

[image: Recessed Button]